# Add list item to ListView without reloading previous list items-Android

Tags: android, listview

I am manually adding list items to list view and list item contains one spinner and edit text views. when add new list item to list view all previously entered data missing. How can i solve this issue ? please help.

Comment: you need persist selected data and load from that in `getView` method, because when you call `notifyDatasetChanged` all view regenerate

Comment: how can i do this.? can u plz give me example code for sppiner and edittext view?